# lateinit property disposableObserver has not been initialized

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have an Activity called First and another activity called SecondActivity.
When i move from first to Second, i have a button which initializes my disposableObserver on button click. I can't use ButterKnife as disposableObserver is not a view. Following code is in my onDestroy

```
 override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (disposableObserver != null && !disposableObserver.isDisposed) {
            disposableObserver.dispose()
        }
    }
```

Now suppose if i am in my second activity and i dont click the button and press the back button , iam taken to First screen but my app crashes because of disposableObserver as it is only initialized when button in my second screen is pressed. I know i can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK to close the app when back button is pressed but i want to move to first screen when back button is prssed in second screen.

I am new to RXJAVA2 and any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using lateinit on disposableObserver?

Comment: @UdeshUK yes.I am using lateinit on disposableObserve

Comment: I just moved my onDestroy code to onComplete and onError. Not sure if it is the correct way but the app works without crashes

Comment: @R2R That is not the optimal way. Observable will get disposed if it succeeded. And don't use late init, just initialize it with a null.

Comment: @UdeshUK Ok Thanks